# CSS Transition : large div disappears completely while animating

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I have some problems with a CSS transition effect. I don't understand why, but it isn't working. Here is a demo that isn't working :

https://codyhouse.co/demo/ink-transition-effect/index.html

Here is an article about how this effect was done (before, when it did work) :

https://codyhouse.co/gem/ink-transition-effect

The code I'm working on to debug is this one :

https://codepen.io/1019/pen/YzxzNGX

HTML file :

```
<body>
  CSS ANIMATIONS TEST
  <div class='cd-transition-layer'>
    <div class="bg-layer"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS file :

```
.cd-transition-layer {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 30;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.cd-transition-layer .bg-layer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 15;
    transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-2%);
    height: 100%;
    width: 2500%;
    background: url('https://i.imgur.com/9uDdPAP.png') no-repeat 0 0;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    animation: cd-sprite 5s steps(24);
    animation-fill-mode: forwards
}

.cd-transition-layer.opening .bg-layer {
    z-index: 15;
    animation: cd-sprite .8s steps(24);
    animation-fill-mode: forwards
}

@keyframes cd-sprite {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-2%)
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-98%)
    }
}
```

Can you please help me find what is wrong ?

Thank you !

EDIT : Okay, weird : it seems the div just completely disappears during the animation before reappering. If I keep focus on the div in the inspector, it stays there. Is it because it's too long (2500% width) ?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Edit done, I added the HTML file.

Comment: Within the  `main.js` there's a init function setting the width/height of `.bg-layer`. It seems to be doing some calculation that are off/wrong when the window width is smaller than the height. I guess the author tried to maintain the original aspect ratio so the inkblob would always be nicely round. IMHO, I would just drop that and just set it to `frames * 100%`. which was already specified as 2500%.  if you do want to keep the aspect ratio, you're going to have to correct the math that calculates the width when `width<height`

Comment: I'm not sure it's about this @Lars since on my demo the bug exist, without javascript involved. I took a video of the bug : the div just completely disappears of the screen (but is still here on the DOM), unless I focus it in the inspector : then, the animation plays correctly. I'll add a big red border on the div to make it more obvious.

Comment: Seems like you're right,  I didn't notice earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Moving large divs

It seems that animating a large div over the screen very fast can cause a render/flicker in webkit based browsers.

If i have to guess, it's probably due to performance reasons, where the browser cuts off things thats are not in the viewport. when moving to the next frame, it will not have the pixels ready to be rendered, resulting in a flicker.
**It becomes more apparent when you remove the `steps(24)` from the animation.**
The div will slide over the screen, and at some point just stop being visible.

## Using background-position instead

When animating, instead of moving a div over the screen, we can also opt to move only the background instead.

```
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/9uDdPAP.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: 2500% 100%;  /* Size is needed to stretch 1 frame to fit the div */
  background-position: 0% 0%; /* we can start from frame 0 */
 animation: cd-sprite 1s steps(24);

/* the animation is the same, we only move the background instead. (in 24 steps) */
@keyframes cd-sprite {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 0%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 100% 0%;
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cd-transition-layer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 30;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.cd-transition-layer .bg-layer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 15;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/9uDdPAP.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: 2500% 100%;
  background-position: 4.16% 0%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  animation: cd-sprite 1s steps(24) infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  border: 36px solid red;
}

@keyframes cd-sprite {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 0%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 100% 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class='cd-transition-layer'>
    <div class="bg-layer"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so so much ! I was asking myself how to make it a background-position instead and scale it. Thanks !